# What does it mean: 'to sleep on somebody'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

How could the following twit be explained:

> Tech companies, y'all **are sleeping on me**. I'm available to hire now and that won't always be the case. Whoever gets me is getting a great team member.

[The source](https://twitter.com/dev_nikema/status/1268974371491639296).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sleep on someone" is an informal phrase; some might consider it a slang. It basically means to ignore someone for whatever reason.

> **[sleep on (someone or something)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sleep+on)** (The Free Dictionary)
>
> (slang) To fail to appreciate or ignore the significance of someone or something. Typically used as an imperative.

Note this is different from "sleep on it", which means

> to think more about something overnight and make a decision about it later (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: So the twit author is demonstrating a piece of impudence, right?

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov It is the other way round. The author is claiming that it is the tech companies who are ignoring him/her or his/her skills. The author might have applied for a job at a number of tech companies and may have been rejected or may not have heard back from them. The author feels that the tech companies are not showing him/her the respect they deserve.